# How to manage android app with one activity and many fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need some help with how manage an android application with one activity and many fragments. 
I choice this pattern because i think it could make the app more rapid and efficient (at least I figured that out from my readings on fragments) but i stuck myself on the very first steps.

The facts are:

- I have one main activity that manages a toolbar and a navigation drawer (left-slide menù) that is a fragment and has a FrameLayout (in activity's xml) to contain the various fragments
- Every voice of the navigation drawer should open a new fragment
- The fragments should share data each other (so the activity is the bridge, right?)

Now: 
If to exchange data among fragments I should use the activity as a bridge, implementing an interface to let fragment-activity communicate each other, how could the activity implements more that one interface to communicate and exchange data with more that on fragment?

I.E.:

Let's suppose I have a *HomeFragment* that is the main view of the app. 
In this fragment I have a *RecyclerView* that handles a list of items.

If I click on one item of the list I should open a new fragment (fullscreen-size so that the new fragment replace completely
the HomeFragment) that shows some details about the item clicked.

I can't do this because my activity already implements an interface for the navigationDrawer so how could i exchange data between fragment and activity?

PS: Sorry for my bad english, I hope I've been clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity can implement as many as fragments that it likes, for example:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    AppleFragment.OnAppleInteractionListener, 
    OrangeFragment.OnOrangeInteractionListener {    

    @Override
    public void onAppleInteraction(int quantity_sold) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrangeInteraction(int quantity_sold) {
    }
}
```

Above code show how easily you can have one activity to implement two fragments.

In separate file you must define the fragments like this:

```
public class AppleFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface OnAppleInteractionListener {
    void onAppleInteraction(int quantity_sold);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class OrangeFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface OnOrangeInteractionListener {
    void onOrangeInteraction(int quantity_sold);
    }
}
```

Comment: but... i thought java only allow to implement one interface o.O 
i'm sorry, i'm very bad informed about this. Thank you for your answer!